# yii2 'route requested' is empty in debugger

Tags: php, forms, yii, yii2, yii-routing

Trying out `Yii2` using the `basic app` example, and having some trouble with routing.  I have a simple login form, and when submitted the correct controller action is called but the $_POST data is empty.  In the Yii debugger, everything looks OK in the logs except this line:

```
3   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\web\Application::handleRequest  Route requested: ''
```

The route is not being handled properly but I don't know what to try next. The 'basic app' comes with a login form view, and the routing is working fine with that form.  Here is my form:

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" id="du-lts-rm-login-form" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DU ID number">
              </div><br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DU Password">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Here is the full trace:

```
    1   18:57:49.306    trace   yii\base\Module::getModule  Loading module: debug
    2   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\web\UrlManager::parseRequest    Pretty URL not   
    enabled. Using default URL parsing logic.
    3   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\web\Application::handleRequest  Route requested:      
    ''
    4   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\base\Controller::runAction  Route to run: site/index
    5   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams    Running action:   
    app\controllers\SiteController::actionIndex()
    6   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\base\View::renderFile   Rendering view file:  
    /home/t/Documents/records/views/site/index.php
    /home/t/Documents/records/controllers/SiteController.php (59)
    7   18:57:49.307    trace   yii\base\View::renderFile   Rendering view file: 
    /home/t/Documents/records/views/layouts/main.php
    /home/t/Documents/records/controllers/SiteController.php (59)
```

The request body is empty, but the routing looks right:

```
        Route   'site/index'
        Action  'app\\controllers\\SiteController::actionIndex()'
```

Also in the response header you can see below that the referer is not correct.  Should look like `'https://localhost/records/web/index.php?r=site/index'.`

```
    Request Headers
    Name    Value
    host    'localhost'
    connection  'keep-alive'
    content-length  '0'
    cache-control   'max-age=0'
    accept  'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
    origin  'https://localhost'
    user-agent  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)        
          Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36'
    content-type    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    referer 'https://localhost/records/web/'
    accept-encoding 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
    accept-language 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    cookie  ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any names or ids for the form inputs. Now it works.